# Positioning Google maps v2 zoom in controls in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I've created a transparent actionbar but the zoom controls and the word 'Google' are behind it. I have no clue how to adjust their location. The default Google Map app on Android phones has them raised above the bottom action bar. Is it possible to reposition the zoom controls and the word 'Google'?

I know you can enable/disable the controls with:

```
 map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the [GoogleMap.setPadding()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method (added in September 2013):

```
map.setPadding(leftPadding, topPadding, rightPadding, bottomPadding);
```

From the API docs:

> This method allows you to define a visible region on the map, to signal to the map that portions of the map around the edges may be obscured, by setting padding on each of the four edges of the map. Map functions will be adapted to the padding. For example, the zoom controls, compass, copyright notices and Google logo will be moved to fit inside the defined region, camera movements will be relative to the center of the visible region, etc.

Also see the [description of how padding works in GoogleMap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#map_padding).

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be helpful for you. I am attempting to implement a similar layout, my solution has been to try and hide the controls on a timed interval like 3 seconds on camera updates.

I think this is the best solution without having to implement custom controls.

```
mapFragment.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                mapFragment.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                Timer t = new Timer();
                TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mapFragment.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

                            }
                        });

                    }
                };

                t.schedule(tt, 3000);


            }

        });
```

This was mostly a proof of concept. But it does work.

Comment: So this just hides them? It looks like you can create a transparent action bar with 4.4. I think they allow you to move them with kitkat

Comment: the idea was instead of moving them to show them only when the map was being interacted with and hide them otherwise. It was a workaround since i have not yet found a way to move them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to move the zoom controls provided with Google Maps you could disable them and create your own custom zoom controls and place them on the top of the map.

Comment: This question is outdated, look at Mark Doliners answer which is correct.

Comment: Well considering this was answered waaaay back in 2013...js

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for map adjustment then use margin or padding on bottom only about `36dp` to `40dp`. Otherwise if you are using location on Map in center then use a property of camera such like:

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
```

It make focus on location at meddium of page.

This:  `mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);` gives you only Zoom level but not focus on location at meddium.